# Why would CreateDelegate be faster than a direct call?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

Note: **I know this code is incompatible with roslyn**

Why would CreateDelegate be faster than a direct call ?

can anyone explain why Delegate.CreateDelegate is faster than a direct call to a delegate?

(.NET 3.5 , debug/release builds alike..)

see example code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var myDelegate = new Func<string, string>((s) => s);


        // Direct Call
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            myDelegate("test");
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("DirectCall: \t\t{0}ms" ,sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        sw.Reset();

        // CreateDeleagetCall

        var myDelegateCaller = (Func<string, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string>), myDelegate.Method);
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            myDelegateCaller("test");
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("CreateDelegateCall: \t{0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: i wouldn't run this in the same process. run your tests independently.

Comment: @DanielA.White .. elaborate ?

Comment: run your code first with 1 method, then run it with the other.

Comment: Same result ( i run the first delegate call outside of the benchmark to allow jitting / inlining )

Comment: Note that there is a discussion on this question already [on reddit /r/csharp](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/3k7sjr/why_would_createdelegate_be_faster_than_a_direct/). The measured results of this could be a result of [this change in Roslyn.](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/1cd6a42f6ab645ea65e24bd1cddea3efb4fa4379) (Additional discussion [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/246)) EDIT: Just to clarify, this isn't Roslyn making the above code faster, just that the above code is analogous to the changes made in Roslyn (and as such why the change was made)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I am aware of this, yet this is pre-roslyn behavior , so not really relevant

Comment: have you tried to compare the IL?

Comment: @user5322657: I think the point is that perhaps the above code essentially replicates/demonstrates the performance impacts that lead the Roslyn team to make the change. That is, `Delegate.CreateDelegate` creates a method invocation such that the JIT doesn't need to rejig the method arguments around. (I don't know if this _actually_ the case here, I'm just suggesting that perhaps it is the case.)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair i believe you are correct, i seem to have stumbled into the "currying" optimization , the same performance is achieved by explicitly  currying  the method (with a null 'this')..

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Just an update, appears we are wrong.. The IL code is the same, the currying technique even improves the createdelegate test aswell! , this seems like a JIT thing